# Powershell Get-AppxPackage not working

Tags: powershell, services

This is the error:
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers

```
Get-AppxPackage : The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices
associated with it.
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AppxPackage
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AppxPackage], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.GetAppxPackageCommand
```

What is the service for that is it disabled through services.msc.Which one is it?

Comment: There are a number of other steps you can try found on the MS support pages [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-store-and-xbox-app-no-longer-working/cbbcb0d0-751c-4c02-9709-7f4344cd803e).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue an the other answer stated was because AppX Deployment Service was disabled.Here's how to enable it:

1. press win + R
2. write regedit
3. press enter
4. goto Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AppXSvc
5. on the right hand double click on start
6. put it to 2 ([automatic start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicestartmode?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0))
7. press ok
8. restart your computer.

you've done it without any repairing or anything

Comment: Can you please explain what is the value 2 for ? and the other values ?

Comment: @Soleil 4 is Disabled. [It should correspond to this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicestartmode?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Answer (score 6):

Apart from what's already mentioned about making sure your services are running/started, you may need to use the legacy loading mode with the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` switch.

[image]

Open an **admin** powershell:

```
# Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.YourPhone -AllUsers

Get-AppxPackage: The 'Get-AppxPackage' command was found in the module 'Appx', but the module could not be loaded.  
For more information, run 'Import-Module Appx'.

# Import-Module Appx

Import-Module: Operation is not supported on this platform. (0x80131539)

# Import-Module Appx -UseWinPS

WARNING: Module Appx is loaded in Windows PowerShell using WinPSCompatSession remoting session; 
please note that all input and output of commands from this module will be deserialized objects. 
If you want to load this module into PowerShell please use 'Import-Module -SkipEditionCheck' syntax.


# Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Select Name, PackageFullName

...
Microsoft.SkypeApp                     Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.68.96.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c
Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_4.9.1252.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.YourPhone                    Microsoft.YourPhone_1.21011.127.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
...
```

You can now use the commands as expected, for example to remove the `YourPhone` package etc.

```
# Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.YourPhone -AllUsers

RunspaceId             : 90cab3d8-569d-4cf8-8f27-b42fbad4634e
Name                   : Microsoft.YourPhone
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
PublisherId            : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
Architecture           : X64
ResourceId             :
Version                : 1.21011.127.0
PackageFamilyName      : Microsoft.YourPhone_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.YourPhone_1.21011.127.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.YourPhone_1.21011.127.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework            : False
PackageUserInformation : {xxxxx: Installed}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
NonRemovable           : False
Dependencies           : {Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.5_2.52012.2002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2_2.2.29512.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                         Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe…}
IsPartiallyStaged      : False
SignatureKind          : Store
Status                 : Ok
```

For more details, see issue discussion [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13138).

Answer (score 4):

> What is the service for that is it disabled through services.msc.Which one is it?

The following services are required to install Windows Store UWP applications

- Client License Service (ClipSVC)
- AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I don't have such a thing as "Windows Store Service (WSService)" in my services.msc.I do have the other two the ClipSVC was not running so I started it.and AppX All of buttons are grayed Can't start that.So only could enable ClipSVC.Tested again and it still doesn't work.

Comment: AppX is the service required to install UWP packages.  You will have to provide the required information necessary to determine the reason your unable to start the service.

Comment: I'll provide any information needed.But I don't know the information needed and how to get them.Please tell me What I need to tell you?

Comment: The error included in the question is all I get.

Comment: Your error is caused by the service being disabled.

Comment: You mean AppX yes it is disabled.But I can't enable it because the buttons are gray how do I enable it?

Comment: Well I went into registry and made it automatic

Comment: Now I have the button.But still can't start it.Changed it to Manual through registry and still the same problem Here's the error when I press start button:
windows could not start the AppX Deployment Service Error 1058: The service cannot be started either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it

Comment: Easy just put it on automatic and then restart the pc It worked Thank you for naming the right services